# type of high order functions

Tags: types, ocaml, higher-order-functions

if I specify the (I think) correct type for a high order function the OCaml compiler rejects the **second** usage of that function.

The code

```
let foo ():string  =
    let f: ('a -> string) -> 'a -> string = fun g v -> g v
    in let h = string_of_int
    in let i = string_of_float
    in let x = f h 23
    in let y = f i 23.0
    in x ^ y
```

leads to the following error message

```
File "test.ml", line 6, characters 14-15:
Error: This expression has type float -> string
       but an expression was expected of type int -> string
```

So the first usage of `f` seems to fix the type of its first parameter to `int -> string`. I could understand that. But what I don't get is that omitting the type restriction on `f` fixes the problem.

```
let foo ():string  =
    let f g v = g v
    in let h = string_of_int
    in let i = string_of_float
    in let x = f h 23
    in let y = f i 23.0
    in x ^ y
```

And moving `f` to global scope fixes the problem, too:

```
let f: ('a -> string) -> 'a -> string = fun g v -> g v

let foo ():string  =
  let h = string_of_int
  in let i = string_of_float
  in let x = f h 23
  in let y = f i 23.0
  in x ^ y
```

Why is it that the first example does not compile while the later ones do?

Comment: I am stumped by your question, but a remark I can make is that `let f (g: 'a->string) (v: 'a): string = g v` does not do what you want: the `'a` is not the same in the two type annotations. You'd better write `let (f : ('a->string) -> 'a -> string) = fun g v -> g v` (which produces the same type error) if you want to constrain `g` and `v` with the same `'a`.

Comment: I would recommend posting this to the OCaml mailing list.

Comment: After reading Gilles's answer, I retract my comment: it **is** the same `'a` in the two annotations, and the mechanism that makes it the same is the mechanism that also causes the confusion. Also confirmed by typing `let f (x:'a) (y:'a) = raise Not_found ;;` or by reading http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/types.html at section "type variables".

Comment: Why post the same question both on StackOverflow and the [OCaml mailing list](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2010/12/ab5f2cbf1c67532e7fd1a9c4e4b5a431.en.html)? As there are knowledgeable camlers on both, you have two correct, disconnected answers (as most mailing-list reader don't read StackOverflow), so one of them was valuable time wasted by a helper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me use a simpler example that illustrates the issue.

```
# let cons0 (x : 'a) (y : 'a list) = x :: y;;
val cons0 : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# let cons1 (x : 'a) (y : 'a list) = x :: y in cons1 1 [];;
- : int list = [1]
# let cons2 (x : 'a) (y : 'a list) = x :: y in (cons2 1 [], cons2 true []);;
This expression has type bool but is here used with type int
# let cons3 x y = x :: y in (cons3 1 [], cons3 true []);;
- : int list * bool list = ([1], [true])
```

`cons0` is a polymorphic function definition, defined at global scope. It's just a trivial wrapper to the `::` operator. Unsurprisingly, the definition works. `cons1` is almost the same as `cons0`, except that its scope is limited to the expression in the `in` body. The change of scope looks innocuous, and sure enough, it typechecks. `cons3` is again the same function, with no type annotation, and we can use it polymorphically in the `in` body.

So what's wrong with `cons2`? The problem is the scope of `'a`: it's the whole toplevel phrase. The semantics of the phrase that defines `cons2` is

```
for some type 'a, (let cons2 (x : 'a) (y : 'a list) = ... in ...)
```

Since `'a` must be compatible with `int` (due to `cons3 1 []`) and with `bool` (due to `cons3 true []`, there is no possible instantiation of `'a`. Therefore the phrase is ill-typed.

If you like to think about ML typing in terms of its usual type inference algorithm, each explicit user variable introduces a set of constraints in the unification algorithm. Here the constraints are `'a = "type of the parameter x"` and `' = "type of the parameter y"`. But the scope of `'a` is the whole phrase, it's not generalized in any inner scope. So `int` and `bool` both end up unified to the non-generalized `'a`.

Recent versions OCaml introduce scoped type variables (as in [Niki Yoshiuchi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443351/type-of-high-order-functions/4443515#4443515)). The same effect could have been achieved with a local module in earlier versions (≥2.0):

```
let module M = struct
    let cons2 (x : 'a) (y : 'a list) = x :: y
  end in
(M.cons2 1 [], M.cons2 true []);;
```

(Standard MLers note: this is one place where OCaml and SML differ.)

Comment: What's interesting is how `f (x: 'a)` differs from `f x`, as both appear to have the same type signature.  The fact that the global scope differs from the `in` scope makes sense, what doesn't is that annotating the type to a generic resolves that generic to an explicit type.  If the behavior was the same for both annotated and non-annotated parameters it would be less weird.

Comment: @Niki: The thing is, you're not annotating the type to a generic, you're annotating with a variable. The scope of the variable is the whole phrase. I think this issue would feel natural if you had to declare type variables. (Also remember that they're *type* variables, not type scheme variables.)

Comment: Thanks for this instructive answer. Do you remember when it was decided that the scope of type variables such as `'a` was the phrase? I am almost certain I remember a time around year 2000 when the scope was just the type (at that time, my comment to the question would have been valid. Now, it's not, I guess...)

Comment: @Pascal: I don't remember ever seeing an ML implementation where the scope of a type variable was a single type annotation. And AFAIK the scope of `'a` has always been the same in OCaml (and probably was in Caml Light too, maybe not in CAML), other than when explicitly delimited through features like local modules and polymorphic records.

Comment: @Gilles: thank you for the answer. Just to state it clear: does this mean that there is no way to get the intended behavior with type annotations?

Comment: @copton: I think there's no way without using a language extension. The oldest extension that permits this is local modules.

Answer (score 4):

This is a real head-scratcher and I wouldn't be surprised if it's a compiler bug.  That said, you can do what you want by explicitly naming the type:

```
let f (type t) (g: t->string) (v: t) = g v in
```

From the manual: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#htoc108

Edit:

This also works:

```
let f g v:string = g v in
```

which has the type signature you are looking for: `('a -> string) -> 'a -> string`

Strange that it doesn't work when you annotate the type of the arguments.

EDIT:

Polymorphic type annotations have a special syntax:

```
let f: 'a. ('a -> string)-> 'a -> string = fun g v -> g v in
```

And the type is required to be polymorphic: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc79

Comment: Your answer makes me wonder if it's not a regression introduced in OCaml 3.12 (at the same time as the circumvention method, so to speak). I have only 3.12.0. Did someone try with an older version?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: same with 3.11.2

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq same with 3.10.2

Comment: oh, no, i should be more attentive, @Niki's exampe doesn't work with 3.11 (and it shouldn't), otherwise i reproduce @copton's behavior.

Comment: @Niki: shouldn't it be "let f (type t) (g: t->string) (v: t) = g v" in the first example?

Comment: @nlucaroni: It's not exactly weak polymorphism, but it's the same issue: the scope of the variable is larger than what you might expect, or in other words generalization happens too late.

Comment: @Niki: according to the caml mailing list locally abstract types (let f (type a) (g : a -> string) (v : a) : string = g v) and polymorphic recursion (let f: 'a. ('a -> string) -> 'a -> string = fun g v -> g v) indeed are the two possible solutions. Both are available in OCaml 3.12.

Answer (score -2):

As a reference point, the equivalent F#

```
let foo ():string  = 
    let f: ('a -> string) -> 'a -> string = fun g v -> g v 
    let h = string 
    let i = string
    let x = f h 23 
    let y = f i 23.0 
    x ^ y
```

compiles.

Comment: One would expect so, since `h` and `i` are both the same hat-typed function in F#, right?

Comment: No, since they're not `inline`, the type inference infers a monomorphic type for each based on usage.  So `h` is `int -> string` and `i` is `float -> string`.  (You can always add explicit types or lambdas to make this more obvious.)  Only `inline`s can have hat types; use them outside an inline context, and they must get 'normal' type instantiations based on usage.